# GWT TabPanel Horizontal Animation

Tags: gwt

As of what I could observe, if you enable animation in tab panel, when you change tabs animation is played vertically. i.e., the current tab slides upwards and the new tab appears from bottom.
Is there a way to do this the other way? Horizontally?

Thanks and Regards,
Pavan Andhukuri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like there is a way with the TabPanel.

If you don't mind upgrading to a Standards Mode page (`<!doctype html>`), TabLayoutPanel does have a method for setting the animation to vertical or horizontal.

See [TabLayoutPanel.setAnimationVertical()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabLayoutPanel.html#setAnimationVertical%28boolean%29)

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, by upgrading a page to standards, will I still be able to support all browsers?
By "all browsers", I mean IE8+, Chrome, FF and Apple Safari.

Comment: Yes, Standards mode will allow you to support all browsers. Check out: [Is Quirks Mode Relevant in 2011?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6404709/770346) and [Differences in Quirks and Standards mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Mode_differences_and_examples)

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the TabLayoutPanel.


[link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/493012/GWT/TabLayoutPanel-auto-height-grow-gwt)


The content of my tabs are dynamic. Like a flex table which increases or decreases based on number of records. I cannot set the height of the panel fixed.. :(

Is there a better way? :)

Comment: I don't know, sorry. :\ Perhaps somebody else knows? In that case, you should open another question for others to see.

Comment: I have embraced GWTQuery. (Google it.) Also instead of using TabLayoutPanel you might opt for creating your own tab bar (perhaps extending FlowPanel). I did this, and lifted some CSS from here: http://css-tricks.com/tabs-with-round-out-borders/, and put it into a ClientBundle that the custom component uses. This results in a detached set of tabs that you could target using GWT Hyperlink. Some day soon I'll post an example on GitHub.

Comment: @Pavan: Did you find a solution for that height problem?