# No color as span defines with DOCTYPE

Tags: html, css, doctype

In html file I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>link</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"   href="page.css" type="text/css"/>

</head>
<body>
    <a target="_blank" href="#" title="#"><span class="nhow">colored</span>not_colored</a>
</body>
</html>
```

in CSS  I have

```
SPAN.NHOW {
    COLOR: red;
}
```

It works fine if there is no next line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

How can I get it working with the "strict" line included? The problem is that there is no color as defined in span class. The link is shown all blue, but colored part should be red.

Comment: It turns out that nhow shoud be in uppercase .

Comment: I did not change the CSS but I change the html to make it equal. So, uppercase both. It works fine. Not sure what is the standard, uppercase or lowercase.  Thank you

Comment: The standard [allows either](http://stackoverflow.com/q/448981/419956), at least for `class` attributes (though you almost never see `ALLCAPS`, it's more common to use `lower-dashed-classes`, `camelCase`, or `PascalCase`). The element should be lowercase though.

Comment: With `there is no next line` I meant if that line is excluded. I have update the question and add full file code. If I delete `that` line or make `nhow` uppercase it works - link is in two colors.

Comment: Hmm, awkward timing. With your latest update I think the question is clear enough. I was about to retract my close vote and post an answer, but other close votes came along to finalize closing at the same moment :P. **I've voted to re-open, because with OP's clarifications I think it's reproducible / clear enough.**

Comment: Please refer [old post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380346/css-styles-not-applied-properly-if-use-doctype)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out..

**HTML**

```
<a target="_blank" href="#" title="#"><span class="nhow">colored</span>not_colored</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.nhow {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the css syntax in wrong way.

This is how it should be

```
.nhow {
    COLOR: #41EDF3;
}
```

Works fine here - https://jsfiddle.net/0ynxfm2v/